# Not rendering svg file in TCPDF

Tags: php, svg, tags, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf for export page.but i am struggle in ImageSVG tcpdf.svg file not rendering properly.My svg file was

```
<svg width="525" height="300" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <g display="" id="front">
  <title>Front 1</title>
  <rect stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFF" id="svg_1" height="166" width="166" y="45" x="291"></rect>
  <rect stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFF" id="svg_2" height="150" width="131" ry="50" rx="50" y="56" x="158"></rect>
  <ellipse ry="58" rx="57" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFF" id="svg_3" cy="134" cx="101"></ellipse>
  <line fill="none" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" id="svg_4" y2="232" x2="41" y1="30" x1="43"></line>
  <g text="New Text" class="textBox">
   <rect stroke-dasharray="5,5" stroke-width="0" stroke="#22C" fill="none" id="svg_5" height="20" width="120" y="50" x="50"></rect>
   <line stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" class="caret" y2="68" x2="50" y1="50" x1="50"></line>
   <text xml:space="preserve" text-decoration="none" text-anchor="undefined" font-style="undefined" font-weight="undefined" font-family="serif" font-size="18" fill="#000000" y="65" x="50">New Text</text>
  </g>
  <object type="image/png" data="base64,encrypted string" id="svg_6" height="204.999989" width="121" y="23.000009" x="309"></image>
 </g>
</svg>



$imag='images/saved_image.svg';
$pdf->ImageSVG($imag, $x=0, $y=0, $w=100, $h=50, $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);
```

I was used image tag and object tag in svg file.But not working.Help me any one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<object>` element is not valid for SVG files.

If you are trying to include an image, you should be using `<image>`.  However I don't know whether TCPDF handles data URLs or not.